# JavaFx Change main class to another main class (seperate class)

Tags: class, javafx

I'm new to JavaFx and have to create a small game. My JavaFx classes works fine but I can't figure out have to change between them. I created a package in eclipse where I have all the display classes (Menu screen class, lauding Screen class, Game display...). Every classes has their main and display fine. But now I can't change from one class to another class. Like from Start menu to game display. I tried initiating the game display class in the menu class and then setScene to game display's scene but it does not work. I'm also confused with either I have to change from stage, scenes or panes.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;
        scene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Menu Screen");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);


        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

2nd Class:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Bucanneer");

        // Setting up Stage, Scene and root
        // Group root = new Group();
        theScene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setScene(theScene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
primaryStage.show();

    }
```

Last try:
I put this in the menu class when you press a button

```
private void backToMenu(){
        Test test = new Test();
        stage.setScene(test.getTheScene());
    }
```

Any advice plz, all I can find are with FXML..
Ps: Sorry for bad  english. Not my native language.

Comment: Your application should only have one subclass of `Application` and one `start()` method.

Comment: But, should change what. stage, scene or panes?

Comment: Depends what you want to happen? Do you want a new window, or do you want to replace the content of the existing window?

Comment: I think its the content that should change like in a game. So I i'm guessing now it has to be scene. Right?

Comment: But wait, if its scene, my backtoMenu() function, is it not supposed to work? I mean even if test class has start method. My just creating an object and switching to its scene

Comment: No-one else knows what you want to happen in your application. The `Stage` represents a window. If you want a new window, create a new `Stage`. If you don't, don't create a new `Stage`.

Comment: Your last comment is incomprehensible to me.